# Allocating memory for small JITted code

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, jit

Is there a way to share pages between different invocations of a JIT assembler in a multi-threaded program?

I'm building a little JIT engine. It seems the basic principle behind JITting is simple enough: `mmap` some space, put machine code into it, `mprotect` it to be executable, cast the start of the code block to a function pointer, and that seems to be all I need for a working system.

However, the `mmap`/`mprotect` combination (and Windows equivalents) only work on whole pages (is this right? if not it throws the whole question off). This means that each time the JIT assembler runs, it has to allocate at least a whole page of space. This is no big deal for a JIT that handles several large functions or even a whole program in one go, but I was mainly interested in handling very short code snippets. Most of the allocated space will not be used by the generated code.

In a single-threaded application this wouldn't be an issue. When it's the JITter's turn to tun it can `mprotect` the code buffer to its heart's content in the knowledge that the code isn't running at that moment. Therefore the space can continue to be used for successive functions until it's actually full. Unfortunately assuming or demanding single-threading seems a bit last-century now.

In a multi-threaded application, dynamically created code may already be running at the same time as other code is being generated. If the JITter tries to play with the protection, it will break something. What are the options for dealing with such a situation?

Things I have considered so far:

- Ignore the issue and allocate a new buffer for each procedure. In practice it would take thousands of allocations to cause a noticeable increase in memory usage and this would likely work fine on the desktop. Philosophically however, saying "screw it we've got lots of hardware" and "nobody will ever stress this system" are kinda repugnant from a design point of view.
- Allocate the buffers with write+execute protection. This seems like the obvious answer but it gives me a bad feeling that I don't have the experience to justify (is this any worse than having a JIT, or a program that calls `mprotect`, in the first place?). Is it safe?
- Have every JITted function try to get a lock on its code buffer. This (intuitively) seems like it would potentially kill performance, inflate code size, and possibly permanently prevent the JITter from ever doing anything if it were done naively.
- Let the JITter have priority access to the code buffers and `mprotect` them at will, and if this causes any existing JITted procedures to segfault, catching them in a signal handler and waiting until the JITter is done. I'm not sure this is actually possible but... eh, it's an idea.

I have tried taking a look at the source of a couple of existing JIT compilers but for the most part they're massive systems that would take a very long time to understand, and which I did not understand, not exactly small examples with clear answers (not that I'm unwilling to read source, I just couldn't get the information I needed from JavaScriptCore or V8; simpler examples are definitely welcome). It seems like this sort of thing might actually be an open question for some projects anyway.

Comment: Why would you even *want* to write protect your JIT code pages? It makes sense to write protect parts of the kernel visible in user space, but write protecting user space against itself seems pointless.

Comment: I ...uh... that may be the obvious answer to a stupid question? Because I am going into this *assuming*, without reasoning, that write+exec is a Bad Thing(tm)?

Comment: @Durandal Well, it does prevent things from going spectacularly wrong (as opposed to just giving a segfault or a whatever that specific error is called) in the admittedly rather unlikely case that buggy code somehow (uninitialized variable, holding onto a pointer after it's `free()`d) writes to the JIT buffer.

Comment: These are not real problems.  You can simply resume generating code where you left off, no need to allocate a new page.  Flipping the page protection back and forth isn't going to affect executing code.  Extremely hard to exploit anyway, the nature of JIT is that the code addresses are entirely unguessable.

Comment: Hans Passant, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT_spraying will not agree with your "nature of JIT is that the code addresses are entirely unguessable.". The spraying is real-world technique.